# Could not view user profile at soundcloud API(401 error)

Tags: soundcloud

I could not view this user profile in soundcloud api

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/27.json?client_id=53167d7cbffc49a8c238b51bd71c4760
```

It is throwing 401 unauthorized error

Let me know what is the possible solution(if i go for pro account i can view as many as profiles i want)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

But its working for my (newly created) client ids.

Therefore you can this:

- go to http://soundcloud.com/you/apps
- select the app and try to save it again, sometimes you may get ask to approve SoundClouds TOS again

If that does not work, create a new application.